# Checking if a binary tree is symmetrical in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, tree

Given a tree, I'm supposed to check if it's symmetrical, or a mirror of itself down the center. I'm missing one edge case and cannot for the life of me figure out what it is. The only error I get on CodeFights is *"Output limit exceeded"*

[Here's what the example tree looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA72y.png)

This is the main function **isTreeSymmetric** assigns its left branch to a variable that invokes the **leftBranch** function and right branch to the **rightBranch** function which recursively return an array.

The reason I used two different functions was because it helped me compartmentalize my thinking given that on the left half of the tree I had to go right to left and vice versa for the right half so I didn't get lost in a tree hole.

The last return statement in isTreeSymmetrical then checks if the returned type values are Arrays followed by a ternary that either checks the left and right arrays or checks the equality of variables lb and rb in the case the values were not arrays.

I've been working on this for what feels like eternity! Help please.

```js
function isTreeSymmetric(t) {
  "use strict";
  if(!t || ( (!t.left && !t.right) && t.value)) return true
  if(!t.left || !t.right) return false

  let left = t.left, right = t.right
  let rb = rightBranch(right), lb = leftBranch(left)
    console.log(`right branch values are ${rb} | left branch values are ${lb}`)
    return Array.isArray( rb || lb ) ?
              rb.every( (e, i) => e === lb[i]) :
                lb === rb

}


//ON RIGHT BRANCH RETURN CHILDREN LEFT TO RIGHT
function rightBranch(n){
  "use strict";
  if(!n) return null

  let value = n.value
  if(!n.left && !n.right) return value

  let left = n.left || null, right = n.right || null;

  return [value].concat(
    rightBranch(left),
    rightBranch(right)
  )

}

// ON LEFT BRANCH RETURN CHILDREN RIGHT TO LEFT
function leftBranch(n) {
  "use strict";
  if(!n) return null
  
  let value = n.value
  if(!n.left && !n.right) return value

  let left = n.left || null, right = n.right || null;
  
  return [value].concat(
    leftBranch(right),
    leftBranch(left))

}

let t = {
    "value": 1,
    "left": {
        "value": 2,
        "left": {
            "value": 3,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        },
        "right": {
            "value": 4,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        }
    },
    "right": {
        "value": 2,
        "left": {
            "value": 4,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        },
        "right": {
            "value": 3,
            "left": null,
            "right": null
        }
    }
}
console.log(isTreeSymmetric(t)) //true
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem.  Among other things, this has no driver program,  you haven't told us what output you *do* get, and there's no apparent attempt to trace the code with either basic **print** statements or a debugger.

Comment: At the very least you should provide sample input, expected output and actual output (kept to a minimum of course).

Comment: You collect all node values of the left and right subtree of the root and compare them, so far so good, but you have to collect them in the same order. So if all nodes have unique values then an easy way to ensure that is to first explore the branch with the lower node value when collecting values (currently you always explore left first).

Comment: Hey guys, sorry it outputs a boolean but there's a hidden test that I can't see the inputs for! The only thing it's giving me is 'Output limit exceeded on test 12. (which is hidden)' I'll add the test cases I do have although my code is passing those so I'm not sure if that'll be much help.

Comment: But collecting the values is actually not good enough, you also have to check if both subtrees have the same structure, which you could do by traversing them simultaneously.

Comment: Line 10 in the snippet is what checks the value. The rightTree function returns its children inside the array from left to right and leftTree returns its children from right to left so the order is correct. There's just some nuanced edge case that is escaping me.

Comment: Look at the example you have given, the right node 2 could have only one child 3 and that node could only have one child 4... returns the same array but it's a different tree structure. As I said, parse both subtrees simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I used two different functions was because it helped me compartmentalize my thinking given that on the left half of the tree I had to go right to left and vice versa for the right half so I didn't get lost in a tree hole.

But there's fundamentally nothing different about handling the left or right sides of your tree. Each L and R is another tree – so all you have to do is compare `(l.left, r.left)` and `(l.right, r.right)`

Below we have a recursive function that creates a tree-like recursive process. It will short-circuit and return `false` as soon as any compared `value`s are not equal.

Instead of using the tree literal you made, I made a simple `Node` constructor to build the tree nodes more easily. This allows me to create a test case for both symmetric and asymmetric trees to verify our function is working correctly

```js
const isTreeSymmetric = tree => {
  const aux = (l, r) => {
    if (l === undefined && r === undefined)
      return true
    else if (l === undefined || r === undefined)
      return false
    else if (l.value === r.value)
      return aux(l.left, r.left) && aux(l.right, r.right)
    else
      return false
  }
  return aux(tree.left, tree.right)
}

const Node = (value, left, right) => ({value, left, right})

const tree1 =
  Node(1,
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))),
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))))
      
const tree2 =
  Node(1,
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))),
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(6000))))

console.log(isTreeSymmetric(tree1)) // true
console.log(isTreeSymmetric(tree2)) // false
```

---

**Code re-use**

The astute observer will notice that the `aux` function above is check for tree *equality* – this is a useful function on it's own so it makes sense to define it outside of `isTreeSymmetric`.

This is probably a better way to write our `isTreeSymmetric` function because it's clearer what's happening and promotes function reuse

```js
const isTreeEqual = (x, y) => {
  if (x === undefined && y === undefined)
    return true
  else if (x === undefined || y === undefined)
    return false
  else if (x.value === y.value)
    return isTreeEqual(x.left, y.left) && isTreeEqual(x.right, y.right)
  else
    return false
}

const isTreeSymmetric = tree =>
  isTreeEqual(tree.left, tree.right)

const Node = (value, left, right) => ({value, left, right})

const tree1 =
  Node(1,
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))),
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))))
      
const tree2 =
  Node(1,
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5))),
    Node(2,
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(5)),
      Node(3, Node(4), Node(6000))))

console.log(isTreeSymmetric(tree1)) // true
console.log(isTreeSymmetric(tree2)) // false
```

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thank you so much! All I had to do was check the case where a null value node was passed and changed 'undefined' to null.

This really helped me gain a deeper understanding of es6 recursion and tree traversal.

Comment: Happy to help. You might want to use `== null` which would cover both `null` and `undefined` cases

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to check the nodes or group it in an array. Just do as you and @naomik have done but return isTreeEqual(x.left, y.right) && isTreeEqual(x.right, y.left). This checks value and symmetry (since a right branch to the right needs to be symmetric with a left branch to the left and a left banch going right needs to be symmetric with a right branch going left).

Code:

```
function isTreeSymmetric(t) {
    if (!t){
        return true
    }
    return isTreeEqual(t.left, t.right)
}

isTreeEqual = function(x, y) {
    if (!x && !y){
        return true
    }
    if (!x || !y){
        return false
    }
    if (x.value === y.value){
        return isTreeEqual(x.left, y.right) && isTreeEqual(x.right, y.left)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy my easiest (non recursive) solution!

```
const isSymmetric =(root) => {
    if (!root) return true;
    
    const L = [root.left];
    const R = [root.right];
    
    while (L.length && R.length){
        const l = L.pop()
        const r = R.pop()
        
        if (!l !== !r || l?.val !== r?.val) return false;
       
        if (l) {
            L.push(l.left)
            L.push(l.right)
            R.push(r.right)
            R.push(r.left) 
        }
    }
    
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I better use single function to traverse the children for the given tree. In the code above the sequence of traversing is swaping the values, so it fails to check the symmetric tree condition. Check the following code and let me know if it works for you.

```js
function isTreeSymmetric(t) {
  "use strict";

  if(!t || ( (!t.left && !t.right) && t.value)) return true
  if(!t.left || !t.right) return false

  let left = t.left, right = t.right
  let rb = traverseTree(right), lb = traverseTree(left)

    return Array.isArray( rb || lb ) ?
              rb.every( (e, i) => e === lb[i]) :
                lb === rb

}



// ON traverseTree
function traverseTree(n) {
  "use strict";
  if(!n) return null

  let value = n.value
  if(!n.left && !n.right) return value

  let left = n.left || null, right = n.right || null;

  return [value].concat(
    traverseTree(left),
    traverseTree(right))

}

  var tree;

  tree = {
    value: 1,
    left: {
      value: 2,
      left: {
        value: 3
      },
      right: {
        value: 4
      }
    },
    right: {
      value: 2,
      left: {
        value: 3
      },
      right: {
        value: 4
      }
    }
  };

console.log(isTreeSymmetric(tree));
```

Comment: This doesn't return the nodes in the correct order. Checking for symmetry, we have to compare the left branches inner nodes to the right branches inner nodes and same with outer. Reason I used separate leftBranch and rightBranch functions was because the leftBranch (which is the left half of the tree) will always return it's right child first and the rightBranch (which is the right half of the tree) always return its left child first. That way when I traverse the values they are in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

here's a little bit of a simpler version that solves this problem in JavaScript by just doing a **level order traversal**, hope it helps!

```
var isSymmetric = function(root) {
    var levels = levelOrder(root)
    for (var x = 1; x < levels.length; x++) {
        var level = levels[x]
        for (var i = 0, j = level.length-1; i < level.length; i++,j--) {
            if (level[i] != level[j]) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
};

var levelOrder = function(node) {
    if (node == null) { return []}
    var discovered = [];
    discovered.push(node)
    var levels = levelOrderTraverse(discovered,[])
    return levels
}

function levelOrderTraverse(discovered,elms) {
    var level = []
    for (var i = 0; i < discovered.length; i++) {
        if (discovered[i] != null) {
            level.push(discovered[i].val)
        } else {
            level.push("null")
        }

    }
    elms.push(level);
    var newlyDiscovered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < discovered.length; i++) {
        if (discovered[i] != null) {
            if (discovered[i].left != null) {
                newlyDiscovered.push(discovered[i].left)
            } else {
                newlyDiscovered.push(null)
            }
            if (discovered[i].right != null) {
                newlyDiscovered.push(discovered[i].right)
            } else {
                newlyDiscovered.push(null)
            }
        }
    }
    if (newlyDiscovered.length > 0) {
        levelOrderTraverse(newlyDiscovered,elms)
    }
    return elms
}
```

also can be found on [my github](https://github.com/dm20/Node-Structures/blob/master/Trees/BinaryTree/Helpers/SymmetricBinaryTree.js)